# How come my NextJS public script won't get bundled?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have three things interacting and I'm not sure how to get them properly bundled.

1. Some dynamic config on the page that is in an inline script
2. A static script in the public folder that uses the dynamic config to generate a global object for a third party script
3. The third party script

The code amounts to this:

```js
const { config: pageConfig } = pageProps;
<Script
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `window.config = ${JSON.stringify(pageConfig)};`,
    }}
/>
<Script src="/scripts/mypublicfile.js" />
<Script src={pageConfig.identity.script_url} />
```

Doing the above generates the following right at the end of `<body>` tag.

```html
<script>window.config = { values: "iexpected"}</script>
<script src="/scripts/mypublicfile.js" />
<script src="https://www.thirdparty.com"></script>
```

I need the first two script tags in the actual `<head>` where the inline script is first and `mypublicfile.js` ends up just being a part of the bundles in `_next/static/` while the third party script can live after them or at the end of the `<body>` tag.

I basically want this (no mention of my public script standalone):

```html
<script>window.config = { values: "iexpected"}</script>
<script src="/_next/static/bundle1.js" />
<script src="/_next/static/bundle2.js" />
<script src="https://www.thirdparty.com"></script>
```

I just want my CDN to know to only cache back `_next/static` without having to also configure things in `scripts` that give a `max-age` of `0` by default.

I have tried a few different permutations and can't seem to figure it out. I may be misunderstanding `Static Optimization`. I use `getInitialProps` but I thought that just meant I couldn't generate `.html` pages. Is that impacting bundling as well?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help as I've not tested it myself but you can have a look at https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head to load scripts in the head and you can also have a look at https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script to use the `beforeInteractive` flag on the script.  That should probably affect the way it's bundled/loaded.

```
import Script from 'next/script'

<Script
  src='https://example.com/public/script.js'
  strategy="beforeInteractive"
/>
```

You can also try `head` with `async` if that doesn't work.

```
import Head from 'next/head'

<Head>
  <script async src='https://example.com/public/script.js'/>
</Head>
```

Comment: This just puts `<script src="scripts/myscript.js" defer"></script>` into the markup before the bundles. This also means the script runs before the inline script.

Answer (score 0):

It took me half a day to figure this out but if you just import your `mypublicfile.js` from inside your page's implementation, it will magically be put inside the bundles that are served to the front-end and loaded in the browser. You just probably want to add a condition around the `import` in order to not have it load server-side. In other words:

```js
// pages/mypage.tsx

// Your normal imports, e.g.
import Image from "next/image";

// What you want to load on the front-end
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  import(
    "../scripts/mypublicfile.js"
  );
}

// Your page's implementation
export default function MyPage() {
  return (
    <Image ... />
  );
}
```